# obtain django dropdown menu item queryset

Tags: django, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a calendar html page, that has a dropdown button to select the different months. How to get to this calendar page is via the `nav bar` that is created at `base.html`

**base.html** - how to get to the calendar page.

```
....
....
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="scheduler_dropdown" href="#"><i class="fas fa-calendar"></i>Scheduler</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="scheduler_dropdown">
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'view_schedule' %}"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>View Schedule</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

what i've build so far:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('schedule/view-schedule/', views.view_schedule, name='view_schedule'),

    path('schedule/view-schedule/?query=month<str:selected_month>', views.view_schedule,
          name='view_schedule_selected_month'),
    ]
```

**Views.py**

```
def view_schedule(request, selected_month=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('post')
    else:
        current_month = date.today().month  
        current_year = date.today().year  

    # a = request.GET  # How to get query set from dropdown menu???
    # print(a)

    args = {
        'month_cal':  monthcalendar(current_year, current_month),
        'month_name': calendar.month_name[current_month],
        'year_name': current_year,
    }

    return render(request, 'static/html/view_schedule.html', args)
```

**view_schedule.html**

```
<div class="card-header">
    Schedule for {{ month_name }} {{ year_name }}

    <form class="date-selector" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="far fa-caret-square-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href={% url 'view_schedule_selected_month' selected_month=1 %}>Jan</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href={% url 'view_schedule_selected_month' selected_month=2 %}>Feb</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href={% url 'view_schedule_selected_month' selected_month=3 %}>Mar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

My problem is that, when I click on the drop down button and select the relevant month `Jan, Feb, Mar`, the url changes, but in my `views.py`, the query set doesn't appear. So I can't extract the query for processing.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I could have just done `print(selected_month)` and it would print the query result.. I got the idea when I was watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmxoGYCFruM

Comment: You could do that, but it is not advisable to process query strings through `urlpatterns`. See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `urlpatterns` to handle query strings. `urlpatterns` handles only the URL itself; query parameters are part of the GET data and are handled within the callback method. You'll need to change the way your HTML, `urlpatterns`, and the view work to accommodate this.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('schedule/view-schedule/', views.view_schedule, name='view_schedule'),
]
```

In your HTML, you'll want a form with a dropdown that GETs the data to the URL above. You can use [the select tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) for this.

And then in the view, you can extract GET data from `request.GET`. Specifically, if you used the `select` tag as suggested above, then the user's choice will be in `request.GET[NAME]` where NAME is the name of the `select` tag.

There are other ways to go about this, depending on aesthetic preferences, etc., but the method I've explained above is likely to be the easiest.

Also, query set (or QuerySet) has a very specific meaning in Django. It refers to a type of object used in database queries [as explained here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/). The results of an HTML form are not "query sets."